# Nested Set Database Design vs Search Tags

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

Currently I categorise my items by giving them a tag that is attached to the item itself. For example, `Men,Accessories,Watch`.

My query is mainly based on search, if scale, plan to look more at Elastic Search.

I'm considering trying Nested Set as Categorising my item.

1. If I use Nested set, does it mean I need three tables? Item Table, Link Table (for each item in Nested Set's ID), Nested Set table
2. In terms of scalability, is it stupid to go my current way of "tag search", would there be a big difference between tag search vs a proper Nested Set?

I tried searching the web but can't seem to find how people are using Nested Set, especially the middle table joining them up.

I need some advice here. Which way should I go about and the reason behind them? I personally prefer tag mainly because it's already working and i got no idea to go about nested set on Laravel's "packages".

I have this nested set table. 
I have another ITEM table
how do i "connect them" up.

```
id
parentid
left
right
depth
```

Comment: Use the three-table approach.  Do not store tags in comma-delimited strings.  SQL has a great data structure for lists; it is called a "table" not a string.

Comment: Nested sets are for hierarchical data. Tags are not necessarily hierarchical. See GL's advice above.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you advice me more on the 3 table appraoch. Lets say My item Belong to 3 category Men, Accessories , Watch. Watch has parent of Accessories and Accessories Parent of Men. So my Middle table has to contain the Item ID X 3 (ID of Watch , Accessories & Men) ? Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

1. No. You need just left and right fields. 2. You can try closures and materialized path. I don"t know nothing about all of them but adjacent list model ain"t so bad.  Maybe there is bottleneck in the hardware?

Comment: i updated my question. Could you look at it? IT's in response to your answer to 1.